# Posting data to mailchimp’s server via their api

Tags: api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

Does anyone know how to post data to mailchimp servers via their api ?
Where can I find code examples in the new
Website ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/update-lists/

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/quick-start/#make-your-first-api-call

Try the above link(s) to see some code example and some useful guides/instructions from mailchimp new website

the url something look like: `https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}`
where `${dc}` is the value in some format like `us19`. You can see your `${dc}` by accessing your mailchimp account.

`Note: The <dc> part of the URL corresponds to the data center for your account.`